# Aeropress: Does inverted method cause premature wear of the rubber plunger gasket?

Tags: aeropress

I got an Aeropress recently since I can no longer access the espresso machine at my company office (first world problem, I know). I've taken a liking to the "inverted" method of brewing. Do any long time users of the Aeropress know if this method will cause the rubbery gasket on the plunger to wear out faster?

I assume the gasket is made to at least withstand boiling water, but it's unsettling to think that I might be drinking rubber contaminated coffee.

Answer (score 2):

No, it won't. I'm an owner of the first generation Aeropress (brown/amber plastic instead of gray), using it daily (skipping weekends) for six years, and the rubber is fine.